# Api call is not stopped calling again and again without any scrolling in Google Paging Library 3

Tags: android, mvvm, rx-java, android-livedata, android-paging-library

I want to implement pagination to show a chunk of list of my desire item view in my app. That's why I choose to use Google newly released paging library i.e Paging library 3. I use Rxjava, Livedata, and ViewModel in my app.
After implementing the paging library, I am facing a weird problem. When I call the method for fetching list, it's calling again and again and not stopped calling the call. In fact, it automatically increases the page number although I did not scroll the list.
Here is the code I tried

`JobListRestApi.kt`

```
interface JobListRestApi {
    @GET("job/list")
    fun getJobResponse(
        @Query("page") pageNumber: Int
    ): Single<Response<JobResponse>>
}
```

`JobListDataSource.kt`

```
class JobListDataSource @Inject constructor(
    private val jobListRestApi: JobListRestApi
): RxPagingSource<Int, Job>() {

    override fun loadSingle(params: LoadParams<Int>): Single<LoadResult<Int, Job>> {
        val position = params.key ?: 1

        return jobListRestApi.getJobResponse(position).toSingle()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map { jobResponse -> jobResponse.jobData.jobs }
            .map { jobs -> toLoadResult(jobs, position) }
            .onErrorReturn { LoadResult.Error(it) }
    }

    private fun toLoadResult(data: ArrayList<Job>, position: Int): LoadResult<Int, Job> {
        val prevKey = if (position == 1) null else position-1
        val nextKey = if (position == data.size) null else position+1

        return LoadResult.Page(data, prevKey, nextKey)
    }

}
```

`JobListRepositoryImpl.kt`

```
class JobListRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val jobListDataSource: JobListDataSource
): JobListRepository {

    override fun getJobs(): Flowable<PagingData<Job>> {
        return Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 20)) {
            jobListDataSource
        }.flowable
    }
}
```

`JobListViewModel.kt`

```
class JobListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val jobListRepository: JobListRepository
): BaseViewModel() {

    val jobs: MutableLiveData<PagingData<Job>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun getJobs() {
        if (jobs.value == null) {
            compositeDisposable += jobListRepository.getJobs()
                .subscribe({
                    jobs.value = it
                }, {
                    handleException(it)
                })
        }
    }

}
```

`JobListFragment.kt`

```
class JobListFragment : BaseFragment<JobListViewModel>() {

    private val jobAdapter: JobAdapter by lazy {
        JobAdapter { }
    }

    override fun getLayoutResource() = R.layout.fragment_job_list

    override fun initWidget() {
        job_recycler_view.adapter = jobAdapter
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        viewModel.getJobs()
    }

    override fun observeLiveData() {
        observe(viewModel.jobs) {
            jobAdapter.submitData(lifecycle, it)
        }
    }
}
```

And the output log is
https://base-url/job/list?page=1

https://base-url/job/list?page=2

https://base-url/job/list?page=3

https://base-url/job/list?page=4

https://base-url/job/list?page=5

https://base-url/job/list?page=6

https://base-url/job/list?page=7

how can I stop calling serial api unless I go to the last item of the chunk in RecyclerView and scroll the list

Comment: I am facing a similar problem, but have checked my API response too. In my case, paging is stuck at Page 2 continuously. Can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, I got the error. In fact, the problem was in my Http response Data. The updated DataSource is given bellow

`JobListDataSource.kt`

```
class JobListDataSource @Inject constructor(
    private val jobListRestApi: JobListRestApi
): RxPagingSource<Int, Job>() {

    override fun loadSingle(params: LoadParams<Int>): Single<LoadResult<Int, Job>> {
        val position = params.key ?: 1

        return jobListRestApi.getJobResponse(position).toSingle()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map { jobResponse -> jobResponse.jobData }
            .map { jobData -> toLoadResult(jobData, position) }
            .onErrorReturn { LoadResult.Error(it) }
    }

    private fun toLoadResult(data: JobData, position: Int): LoadResult<Int, Job> {
        val prevKey = if (position == 1) null else position-1
        val nextKey = if (data.hasMore) position+1 else null

        return LoadResult.Page(data.jobs, prevKey, nextKey)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You tell Paging there is no more to load by returning `null` for `prevKey` and `nextKey` in`LoadResult.Page`

Since its infinitely appending, it looks like you never set `nextKey` to `null`. Perhaps you meant to check `data.isEmpty()` instead of `key == data.size`?

Comment: thanks for your answer brother. actually The error was in my HttpResponse. I figured it out

Comment: I am facing a similar problem, but have checked my API response too. In my case, paging is stuck at Page 2 continuously. Can you please help?

Comment: @AtishAgrawal
i am facing the same problem
did you solve it?

Comment: @MohammadSommakia I did solve it somehow. But I am unable to recall it. It has been a long time now. It was probably an issue with my API Response.

Comment: For me no it's not an API problem, the library keeps calling the API without stopping and I didn't find out why :(

Comment: Paging will automatically continue to load until it fills prefetchDistance or `nextKey == null`, so make sure you are setting that eventually. If you are using RemoteMediator, make sure to also eventually pass `endOfPaginationReached = true`, otherwise Paging will think you haven't reached the end yet!

Comment: @AtishAgrawal 
 I have the same situation as yours can you help me how you solved it. The api call is stuck at page 2 and is happening continously.

Comment: @MohammadSommakia did you solve it ? can you please help me.

Comment: Unfortunately I didnt